# to_csv keeps on looking for a file and not creating one

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas

```
if os.path.isfile('%s.csv' %code):
    print('located %s, next step, update.. \n')
    update_stocks(code=code)
else:
    print('data for %s does not exist, downloading data...\n' %code)
    print(code)
    df = quandl.get('%s' %code, authtoken=authority)
    df = df[['Open','High', 'Low', 'Close']]
    print(df.tail())
    df.to_csv('%s.csv' %code,)
```

the last line here is bugging me, the error that shows is

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GOOG/KRX_028050.csv'

which is right, but i thought that to_csv creates a file? 
any help would be appreciated thank you guys

Comment: Hmmm, maybe `directory` is missing?

Comment: As @jezrael says - it'll create the "file" - but it won't create any directories...

Comment: thanks guys, so i guess I have to make a directory, otherwise I wont be able to save anything with a / sign in it? honestly right now i really dont need a directory or want one for this program,and also thanks guys, I should have seen that one coming